# What is the opposite to being "consumed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the opposite to being "consumed" in a sense of being soon to be "consumed" but not yet happened to be. Or, to put it in a different way, is there a nicer way (synonym?) to say "unconsumed"?

*Background & context*:
The subject of "consumption" here is a character (a symbol/letter from a long line of text).

I am working on a parser, so for each given rule the outcome of feeding a character to the parser can be either consumed (we can move on to the next character) or unconsumed meaning we should try to apply another rule if any, for either outcome there must be a type that represents it, the type needs a name, hence the question, I know I can go with unconsumed but it sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: I think this is a slightly silly question. By definition, *food* is invariably stuff that's destined to be eaten. We specifically identify food that didn't "fulfill its destiny" as [***uneaten food, scraps, leftovers***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scrap) because there's often some negative implication (there was too much food, it was unpalatable, or otherwise unwanted, whatever). But before it reaches that final hurdle (getting ingested), "not-yet-eaten" food could be *grain, cows, foodstuffs, groceries, cooking, dinner, a plateful, a forkful* or whatever. It's just too broad-based.

Comment: In a program I am working on it is crucial to give things terse and concise names. So I need to make clear difference between stuff that has been consumed and the rest that, for some reason, left unconsumed to be considered for consumption later. I know my question sounds funny, but it wasn't the intent.

Comment: @bonomo what is the matter or substance that is soon to be consumed?

Comment: I don't see how it's meaningful to continue referring to something as "food" *after it's been eaten*. For a while it's "stomach contents", then it's [chyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyme), but pretty soon it's all just sh*t anyway. To put it more politely, *all* food is food that hasn't yet been eaten. Perhaps in your specific context you might use words like *edible* or *saleable*, but there would need to be some reason why it's not just "food".

Comment: @MarioElocio, it is a character (a symbol/letter in a long line of text) I am working on a parser, so for each given rule the outcome of feeding a character to the parser can be either `consumed` (we can move on to the next character) or `unconsumed` meaning we should try to apply another rule if any, for either outcome there must be a type that represents it, the type needs a name, hence the question, I know I can go with `unconsumed` but it sounds a bit awkward

Comment: You should explain why you need a word that is equivalent to "unconsumed" in your post. BTW what about "uneaten"?

Comment: This is precisely why variable naming is explicitly off-topic. There's nothing wrong with *unconsumed*; but if you want a terse name, call it *Carl* or *Tom*. It doesn't matter in an internal name. It **might** matter if the word is to be presented to the user, in which case you need to put all of the comments into the question and restate it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, first of all why are you so mean? secondly, the question itself doesn't have anything to do with variables and works for a general situation, thirdly it does matter for being able to make sense of the code when you read it, lastly, if you don't feel like making an effort to read or answer just move on, thank you for your help

Comment: I'm sorry you think it's mean to point out [what is already in the help text](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and what has been stated in others' comments on similar questions -- and if you read my comment, you will find first that I have made an effort to read and answer, as I believe *unconsumed* to be fine; secondly that I have given advice on how I think the question may be made on-topic; and thirdly that at least one other person considers that comment to be useful. But if you don't, feel free to ignore its advice. The internet is a free country.

Comment: I think the crucial point here really is that *unconsumed* is perfectly fine. Your only objection to it — not even expressed, merely implied — is that it's somehow not "nice" enough. You want a "nicer" word. But you have't defined what "nicer" even is. So it is entirely in the eye of the beholder. Shorter? Longer? No prefixes? More vowels? Borrowed from Russian? "Carl"? Well why not, I for one humbly submit that "Carl" very much *is* a nicer word. So I don't see anything mean about Andrew's comment; it's actually right on the money.

Comment: You also got the shot-from-the-hip *produced*, which I assume will be about as useful to you as *Carl*, and yet I can't really delete or even downvote it as inappropriate. The only thing it's got going against it is that it's much less specific, but that's pretty much inevitable as you start off with a very specific word.

Comment: @271 As this is related to **parsing**, I think *digested*, *undigested* or *semi-digested* might be better choices, eg this [handout](http://www.learningace.com/doc/851363/a653f0e6e6e6ef8c201cba22548cd7b7/08-bottom-up-parsing)

Comment: You can thank @Kris for editing your question if your post has any chance of being reopened. Seriously, how much effort would it have been for you to have copied and pasted your comments in the actual post? Comments from time to time are deleted by the mods (this has happened to me) hence our encouragement to you to be more precise and to say "why" in your question. IMO this question has a good chance of getting the computer geeks in a flurry of excitement. (Then maybe not.) :)

Answer (score 1):

***unfinished*** is a possible word agreeing with *consuming* yet not necessarily about food alone.

-1. In the context of food, it refers to the part of food in the dish after some has been eaten.

(LA Kelly, *Return to Alastair*, Bk.3)

> He went back to his **unfinished food**, and she studied him in silence.

(Kerry-Anne Samuel, *Angel Demon*)

> We sat in silence eating for a while, the food was not very nice, but I endured eating it, well picking it really. Louis was picking at his food also.
>   ...
>   I averted my eyes down to my plate of **unfinished food**.

(Sonia Gensler, *The Revenant*)

> During supper, Mother narrowed her eyes at the **unfinished food** on my plate. "Are you taking ill, Willie?"

-2. However, this phrase is now idiomatic and is being used widely as a general euphemism for *leftovers* or  *wasted food*.

*meta*: *Consume* does not necessarily relate to food alone. The OP has not specified the context.

---

[Edit per new light on context]:
The very choice of "consumption" (I know it is part of the jargon related to parsing, yet) seems to be the cause of all the difficulty. I would suggest looking for a new **set** of expressions rather than an antonym for "consumption",

such as:
*processed* – *unprocessed* – *in-process* – *to-process*;
…

Comment: The OP in the comments section says "the outcome of feeding a character". But you're right about the open interpretation of the term, he really needs to be more specific in his post.

Comment: The question is related to the parsing of characters, not food, qv comment by OP.

Answer (score 0):

*Consumption* and *production*. *Consume* and *produce*.